# Error installing Ubuntu 22.04.1 alongside

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 22.04, usb-drive, reboot

I installed Ubuntu using  dual-boot mode using balena etcher to flash the USB and shrinked the home partition in order to diminish the risk of losing data. I followed this tutorial and it all worked well until restarting:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ag8apC9cCOA&t=644s

When I restarted, I got the following errors:
[FAILED] Failed mounting /cdrom
[FAILED] Failed to start Ubuntu live CD installer.

Did anyone encounter this kind of issue ?

Thank you

Comment: It is unclear what partition you shrinked and why. Also there is a lot of written manuals on how you install Ubuntu.

Comment: The C partition on Windows in order to have separate partitions for root and home